# Magento 2: Create the dynamic excel file

Tags: magento2

How can I create the **excel** file in Magento root directory with my dynamic data in the controller file.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: have you tried so far?

Comment: @AmitBera No, i have no idea , how can i do

Comment: excel or csv file need?

Comment: @AmitBera excel file.

Comment: @AmitBera Any idea how can i export the CSV in magento 2?